# SQL Join Ads with their Fields show fields as columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have an Ads Table and an Ads_field Table and when i join i will get multiple rows for one ad because they have multiple fields

Is there a way to show the fields as columns?

```
SELECT Ads.CITY_ID,Ads.PRICE,Ads.CREATED_DATE,Ads.HAS_IMAGES, 
 Ads.TITLE, Ads.DESCRIPTION, loc_cities.name as city, CATEGORY.NAME as           
 category_name, loc_countries.country_name as 
 country,Ads_fields.field_value
 FROM Ads
 INNER JOIN loc_cities ON Ads.CITY_ID=loc_cities.id
 INNER JOIN CATEGORY ON Ads.CATEGORY_ID=CATEGORY.ID 
 INNER JOIN loc_countries ON Ads.country_code=loc_countries.ID 
 INNER JOIN Ads_fields ON Ads.ID=Ads_fields.ad_id
    WHERE CONVERT(Ads.TITLE USING utf8) LIKE '%reqqa%' 
 or CONVERT(Ads.DESCRIPTION USING utf8) LIKE '%reqqa%'
 or CONVERT(loc_cities.name USING utf8) LIKE '%reqqa%'
 or CONVERT(loc_countries.country_name USING utf8) LIKE '%reqqa%'
 or CONVERT(CATEGORY.name USING utf8) LIKE '%reqqa%'
 LIMIT 50
```

[image: database table]

Comment: A while loop in PHP would be the simplest, quickest, and most scalable solution.

Comment: Definitely True Yet i want to implement a keyword search using a single query a while loop would serve best to fetch and display data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is show the field_value as a string comma separated

```
  SELECT 
      Ads.CITY_ID,Ads.PRICE
      , Ads.CREATED_DATE,Ads.HAS_IMAGES
      , Ads.TITLE
      , Ads.DESCRIPTION
      , loc_cities.name as city
      , CATEGORY.NAME as  category_name
      , loc_countries.country_name as country 
      , group_concat(Ads_fields.field_value)
   FROM Ads
   INNER JOIN loc_cities ON Ads.CITY_ID=loc_cities.id
   INNER JOIN CATEGORY ON Ads.CATEGORY_ID=CATEGORY.ID 
   INNER JOIN loc_countries ON Ads.country_code=loc_countries.ID 
   INNER JOIN Ads_fields ON Ads.ID=Ads_fields.ad_id
      WHERE CONVERT(Ads.TITLE USING utf8) LIKE '%reqqa%' 
   or CONVERT(Ads.DESCRIPTION USING utf8) LIKE '%reqqa%'
   or CONVERT(loc_cities.name USING utf8) LIKE '%reqqa%'
   or CONVERT(loc_countries.country_name USING utf8) LIKE '%reqqa%'
   or CONVERT(CATEGORY.name USING utf8) LIKE '%reqqa%'
   GROUP BY  Ads.CITY_ID,Ads.PRICE
      , Ads.CREATED_DATE,Ads.HAS_IMAGES
      , Ads.TITLE
      , Ads.DESCRIPTION
      , loc_cities.name 
      , CATEGORY.NAME 
      , loc_countries.country_name 
   LIMIT 50
```

Comment: , loc_cities.name as city
      , CATEGORY.NAME as  category_name
      , loc_countries.country_name as country    dont work had to remove aliases in the last three lines

Comment: @AhmedSaleh   correct  . answer  updated  (wrong  copy &paste )